# Кастомный макет через RecyclerViewAdapter

Tags: android, mediaplayer, recyclerviewadapter

Я использую `RecyclerView` для отображения списка, и в этом списке в макете адаптера, я хочу реализовать `MediaPlayer` и различные `view` элементы, проблема в том, что все ссылки и метод реализации должны происходить в классе адаптера, я получаю ссылки на `TextView` во `ViewHolder` но с `MediaPlayer` возникли проблемы.

Посоветуйте литературу или дайте пожалуйста ссылки на правильный метод реализации `MediaPLayer`и всего остального как в обычном классе или фрагменте в `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

**Дополнение**

```
class RecyclerVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerVAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static List<Head> mHead;

RecyclerVAdapter(List<Head> contentItem) {
    mHead = contentItem;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.contents, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    viewHolder.mDuaAR.setText(mHead.get(position).getHead());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mHead.size();
}

static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView MyHead;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        MyHead= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.head);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Кто-нибудь что-нибудь понял? Я лично нет. Причем тут медиаплеер, причем здесь `TextView`?

Comment: @Barmaley у меня в класс `RecyclerViewAdapter` вложен класс `ViewHolder` в котором я получаю ссылки на `view` элементы из макета который использует `RecyclerViewAdapter`, далее в методе `onBindViewHolder` я задаю текст по этим ссылкам. И в этом нет проблем, но я хочу чтобы у меня в макете который использует  `RecyclerViewAdapter` был `MediaPlayer` соответственно со всеми вытекающими из него потребностями. Сейчас добавлю код адаптера.

Comment: Класс `MediaPlayer` используется для управления воспроизведением аудио/видео файлов и потоков. Каким образом вы хотите его поместить в макет итема `RecyclerView`? А главное для чего?

Comment: @eugeneek, Да, помню, вот о том, каким образом поместить и спрашиваю. Для того, чтобы в моем прокручиваемом списке на каждом пункте была кнопка плей с прогресс строкой.